# Do there exist or have there ever existed "gang war referees"?

Tags: diplomacy, organised-crime

In the game, "Assassin's Creed Syndicate", a gang war mission starts with [a man in a top hat](https://youtu.be/_KBVn9oPXwo?t=31) telling you that a gang war has been declared, and seemingly acting as a neutral referee.

Similarly, in "The Raid 2: Redemption", An old man seeming to be an overseer oversaw the negotiations between the Yakuza and Banggun.

Do these kind of referees between Gangs actually exist?

Answer (score 4):

In 1931 [*The Commission*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Commission_(mafia)) was formed by the [Five Families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Families) (five leading New York City mafia families), one of which was that led by gangsters [Charlie [Lucky] Luciano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_Luciano), [Meyer Lansky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyer_Lansky), [Benjamin [Bugsy] Siegel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugsy_Siegel) and [Salvatore Maranzano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvatore_Maranzano).

Luciano's conception was that it would act as a *Board of Directors* for the New York Mafia, refereeing disputes between the families, similar to the eponymous body of a legal incorporation. Luciano was the first *Chairman* of the Board.